# Add space for formatting before Xelement in XML file usin C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xdoc

I am trying to add one  XElement to an XML file where  element is already present in a specific format(see the line 2 where space is present before the Student element), however when i add the Xelement, **how could i add a space before the Xelement  ? See line 5 in below images for difference of space for formatting ?**

Creating the Tag here:

```
    XElement newStudent = new XElement("Student");
    newStudent.SetAttributeValue("Name", "jhonny");
    newStudent.Add(new XText("\n        "));


    XElement stuSetting = new XElement("Subject");
    stuSetting.SetAttributeValue("Name", "C#");
    stuSetting.SetAttributeValue("Mark", "95");

    newStudent.Add(stuSetting);
    newStudent.Add(new XText("\n  "));
```

Add in the existing file by loading it using XDocument:

```
        StudentsXmlFile.Element("Students").Add(newStudent);
        StudentsXmlFile.Element("Students").Add(new XText("\n"));
```

**Required:**
[image]

Currently Getting output:

[image]

Comment: Do not add you own return '\n'.  It is automatically added inside the XDocument.  The return is creating the issue with the indenting.

Comment: @jdweng: if i dont put \n , it creates the xml element in one line

Comment: You are adding attributes which are always on same line as tag.  The code you post and the picture you posted are not consistent.  Try SetValue instead of SetAttributeValue.